# Update Hosted ArcGIS Feature Service Schema Issue

Tags: arcgis-online, feature-service, fields-attributes

I am trying to update a field length of a hosted feature service in ArcGIS Online.  I load the update definition page by going to the Admin REST page of the service, and clicking Update Definition:

[image: Update Definition Link]

I then take the JSON and copy/paste it into an editor, like Notepad++.

I find the field I want to update, and change the length.  In this case I want the Category field to have a length of 70, rather than 50:

[image: Change Field Length]

I then copy/paste the JSON back to the Update Definition page and click Update Service Definition, and receive a success message:

[image: Success Message]

But when I go back to the REST page, CATEGORY is still 50 in length:

[image: Length Still 50]

Not sure what the issue is here.  Do I need to set ASync to True?

Comment: I am confident the issue is the schema cannot be changed because there is a data in the service.  I am sure on the backend the AlterField GP runs to make changes, but that is a limitation when using that GP.  I also wonder if some parts of the definition are simply not supported to be changed using this operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was confirmed that not all definition elements could be updated.  Additionally, when data was present in the service, the schema was locked.